# Javascript regex date format dd/mm/yy

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm a very beginner in regex.
I need to have a date in javascript in format dd/mm/yy; I have this regex expression to have the date:

```js
var myDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\b(\d\/)/g, '0$1');
```

I need to change the regex expression above to have the year in two digits only, something like: 27/04/16

Comment: Add `.replace(/\d{2}(\d{2})/, "$1")` replacement.

Comment: Thanks  Wiktor Stribiżew, but with your suggested regex the month comes in one digits: 27/4/16

Comment: Does it? `var myDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\b(\d\/)/g, '0$1').replace(/\d{2}(\d{2})/, "$1");`?

Comment: You're right!! It works!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: toLocaleDateString() should be used with a locale parameter, such as "en_US",  if a particular string format is required, otherwise it will return the default format of the user's locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second replace would do the trick:

```
var myDate = new Date()
    .toLocaleDateString()
    .replace(/(\d+)/g, "0$1")
    .replace(/\d+(\d{2})/g,"$1");
```

I've removed the `\b` from the first replacement since grabbing just the digits is enough.  This replacement just pads all the numbers with a leading 0.  The second replacement will trim each number to just the 2 least significant digits.

Comment: Yes it will. I wonder if you can prove it. However, this is not an optimal pattern.

Comment: I see that my answer is pretty much the same as yours but I opted for the `+` rather than the specific `{2}`.  What do you mean by 'prove it'?  The first replace adds a 0 to all numbers and the second trims them all to the least significant 2 digits.  Also you need to add the global switch to your comment above.

Comment: The global switch is redudant: how many years are there in a date string? `\d+` matches all digits it can and starts *backtracking* - it is inefficient. But it does not matter here since the input string is really small. My wife finally finished e-shopping, but the answer is accepted already. Code-only answers are not helpful when we deal with regex and to get upvotes, you'd better explain what your pattern is doing.

Comment: Noted.  I'll show my work next time.  I prefer more general matches because I expect users to break everything they can.  In this case it's probably overkill since the input is from JS, but even then, I'm not familiar with every date string format from all locales.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function addPadding(digit)
{
    return (digit < 10) ? '0' + String(digit) : digit;
}
var date = new Date();
dateString = addPadding(date.getDate()) + "/" + addPadding((date.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" +date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: getDate() and getMonth() will return single digits with no leading zero for values < 10.

Comment: I have Edited my Answer

Answer (score 0):

A small correction on Vishnu Ravi's post:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + (date.getDate()) : date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1);
var year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
var dateString = day  + "/" + month + "/" + year;
console.log(dateString);
```